# Relational query with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So I am trying to get the comments associated with a blog, Using Parse Javascript SDK
here is my code

```
var Blog = Parse.Object.extend("Blog");
var query = new Parse.Query(Blog);
query.get("tFlENZ3ege", {
    success: function(blog) {
        // Next, retrive comment based on blog
        var commentQuery = new Parse.Query(Comment);
        commentQuery.equalTo("parent", blog);
        commentQuery.find({
           success: function(comments) {
               console.log("Success getting comments");
           },
           error: function(object, error) {
               console.log(error);
           }
        });
    },
    error: function(object, error) {

    }
});
```

I am able to retrieve the blog object based on the objectId.
However, I can't figure out how to get the associated comment objects

Comment: your code looks good, what you are getting inside `console.log("Success getting comments");` and add details about your collections structure.

Comment: see error log inside parse.com data browser